# argument of type incompatible with LPVOID

Tags: c++

Last error I have and can't seem to fix it.

Issue: E0167 argument of type "MoveResponseToInventory_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPVOID *"

```
# include "MinHook.h"

using MoveResponseToInventory_t = bool(__fastcall*)(LPVOID, int);
MoveResponseToInventory_t pMoveResponseToInventory = (MoveResponseToInventory_t)(base + 0x54C9C00);

MoveResponseToInventory_t fpMoveResponseOrig;

bool __fastcall MoveResponseToInventory_Hooked(LPVOID a1, int a2) {

    fpMoveResponseOrig(a1, a2);

    UnlockEverything();

    MH_RemoveHook(pMoveResponseToInventory);

    return false;
}

void SetupYourHook() {
    if (MH_CreateHook(pMoveResponseToInventory, MoveResponseToInventory_Hooked, &fpMoveResponseOrig) != MH_OK) { //&fpMoveResponseOrig is throwing error here

        printf("Failed to hook...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly which line does the error message point to???

Comment: Note that `LPVOID*` is equivalent to `void**`.  Are you sure you're invoking this function correctly?

Comment: MoveResponseToInventory_t fpMoveResponseOrig;

Answer (score 0):

`MH_CreateHook()` expects a pointer to a `void*` in the 3rd parameter, but you are giving it a pointer to a `MoveResponseToInventory_t` instead. So you need to use a type cast, eg;

```cpp
MH_CreateHook(..., reinterpret_cast<void**>(&fpMoveResponseOrig))
```